# Reverse geocoding for amazon fireos devices

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am using below code for reverse geocoding this works on android perfectly.But Amazon fire OS doesn't support this.Do we have any code for Amazon Fire OS to calculate reverse geocoding.("Now I am using google api It needs internet and slow I want something like below code which does the work quickly")

```
   public String reverseGeoCodeConversion(String location) {
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        String lattitude = location.split(":")[0];
        String longitude = location.split(":")[1];
        Geocoder geocoder = new 
        Geocoder(MyApplication.getMyApplicationContext(), 
        Locale.getDefault());
        int result = 1;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lattitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            Log.d("reverseaddress", address.getAddressLine(address.getMaxAddressLineIndex()));
            return address.getAddressLine(address.getMaxAddressLineIndex());
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "NA";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Amazon_Maps_API_on_the_Kindle_Fire#Understanding_Geocoding_and_Reverse_Geocoding), the Amazon Fire supports the `android.location.Geocoder` interface. What does [`Geocoder.isPresent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent()) return on your device?

> Now I am using google api It needs internet and slow

The `Geocoder` interface needs the internet, too.

Comment: Geocoder.isPresent() is giving me true But             addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lattitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), result);
this code throws exception like " java.io.IOException: Geocoding failed, please look into the logs for more details!"